# nginx - php connect() unix socket failing

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I am running alpine 3.12 container with a few custom configuration like so:

```
FROM alpine:3.12

[some irrelevant stuff]

# Switch to use a non-root user from here on
USER nobody

# Expose the port nginx is reachable on
EXPOSE 8080

# Let supervisord start nginx & php-fpm
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]

# Make sure files/folders needed by the processes are accessable when they run under the nobody user
RUN chown -R nobody.nobody /var/www/html && \
  chown -R nobody.nobody /run && \
  chown -R nobody.nobody /var/lib/nginx && \
  chown -R nobody.nobody /var/log/nginx

# Configure a healthcheck to validate that everything is up&running
HEALTHCHECK --timeout=10s CMD curl --fail http://127.0.0.1:8080/fpm-ping
```

I have my nginx.conf with the following data:

```
worker_processes 1;
error_log stderr warn;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    # Define custom log format to include reponse times
    log_format main_timed '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                          '$request_time $upstream_response_time $pipe $upstream_cache_status';

    access_log /dev/stdout main_timed;
    error_log /dev/stderr notice;

    keepalive_timeout 65;

    # Write temporary files to /tmp so they can be created as a non-privileged user
    client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_temp;
    proxy_temp_path /tmp/proxy_temp_path;
    fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/fastcgi_temp;
    uwsgi_temp_path /tmp/uwsgi_temp;
    scgi_temp_path /tmp/scgi_temp;

    # Default server definition
    server {
        listen [::]:8080 default_server;
        listen 8080 default_server;
        server_name _;

        sendfile off;

        root /var/www/html/public;
        index index.php index.html;

        location / {
            # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        # Redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root /var/lib/nginx/html/public;
        }

        # Pass the PHP scripts to PHP-FPM listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
            expires 5d;
        }

        # Deny access to . files, for security
        location ~ /\. {
            log_not_found off;
            deny all;
        }

        # Allow fpm ping and status from localhost
        location ~ ^/(fpm-status|fpm-ping)$ {
            access_log off;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
    }
    
    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain application/xml text/css text/js text/xml application/x-javascript text/javascript application/json application/xml+rss;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    
    # Include other server configs
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

and my supervisord config such as:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
logfile=/dev/null
logfile_maxbytes=0
pidfile=/run/supervisord.pid

[program:php-fpm]
command=php-fpm7 -F
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
autorestart=false
startretries=0

[program:nginx]
command=nginx -g 'daemon off;'
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
autorestart=false
startretries=0
```

and in my php-fpm/www.conf:

```
[global]
; Log to stderr
error_log = /dev/stderr

[www]
; The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.
; Valid syntaxes are:
;   'ip.add.re.ss:port'    - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv4 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   '[ip:6:addr:ess]:port' - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv6 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   'port'                 - to listen on a TCP socket to all addresses
;                            (IPv6 and IPv4-mapped) on a specific port;
;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

; Enable status page
pm.status_path = /fpm-status

; Ondemand process manager
pm = ondemand

; The number of child processes to be created when pm is set to 'static' and the
; maximum number of child processes when pm is set to 'dynamic' or 'ondemand'.
; This value sets the limit on the number of simultaneous requests that will be
; served. Equivalent to the ApacheMaxClients directive with mpm_prefork.
; Equivalent to the PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN environment variable in the original PHP
; CGI. The below defaults are based on a server without much resources. Don't
; forget to tweak pm.* to fit your needs.
; Note: Used when pm is set to 'static', 'dynamic' or 'ondemand'
; Note: This value is mandatory.
pm.max_children = 100

; The number of seconds after which an idle process will be killed.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'ondemand'
; Default Value: 10s
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;

; The number of requests each child process should execute before respawning.
; This can be useful to work around memory leaks in 3rd party libraries. For
; endless request processing specify '0'. Equivalent to PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS.
; Default Value: 0
pm.max_requests = 1000

; Make sure the FPM workers can reach the environment variables for configuration
clear_env = no

; Catch output from PHP
catch_workers_output = yes

; Remove the 'child 10 said into stderr' prefix in the log and only show the actual message
decorate_workers_output = no

; Enable ping page to use in healthcheck
ping.path = /fpm-ping
```

So my question: Where is this error log coming from???

```
[crit] 9#9: *2 connect() to unix:/var/run/php7.3-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php7.3-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1:8080"
```

It should really not be triggered, since I never specify php-fpm to listen to this socket. Where does it come from???

Comment: Can you check if there is any config file under ```/etc/nginx/conf.d/```